# Problema de conexión Mysql-Netbeans

Tags: mysql, netbeans

Cuál es el error de conexión de Mysql con Netbeans?
De hecho hice otro código del DriverManager y me funciona perfectamente, no entiendo cuál podría ser el error.

`````````
package centro.pkgint.modelo;

import com.mysql.jdbc.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class Conexion {
    Connection con;
    String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centro_int";
    String user="root";
    String pass="1234";
    public Connection Conectar () {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
    ````````         con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centro_int?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "1234");
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
        }
    return con;
    }
}
``````
`````````

Comment: Imprime el mensaje de error en el  `catch` y agrégalo a la pregunta pulsando en [edit]  para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Uusas maven? ayuda mucho a la gestión de las bibliotecas y recursos,. Saludos

Comment: Creo que es importante aclarar que NetBeans no esta haciendo ninguna conexión, Netbeans solo sirve para compilar el que trata de hacer conexión es tu código. Por otro lado poner un catch sin nada entre las llaves es malisima practica por que impide ver a causa del cualquier error como este que se te presenta.

Answer (score 0):

hice una conexión con DriverManager, intenta esto:

```
public DBConexion(){
     try{
         //Cargamos el driver
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
         String db="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centro_int";

         //AGREGAR LIBRERIA JDBC
         con=(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(db, "root", "1234");

     } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex ) {
         Logger.getLogger(DBConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }

}
```

Te recomendaria a parte un método para retornar la conexión:

```
//MÉTODO PARA RETORNAR LA CONEXIÓN
public Connection getConexion(){ 
   return this.con;   
}
```

Y por seguridad, otro para cerrar la conexión y no dejarla abierta:

```
//MÉTODO PARA CERRAR LA CONEXIÓN
 public void cerrarConexion(){
     try{
         con.close();
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(DBConexion.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
  }
```

---

lo que cambio en la conexión respecto a la tuya fue esto:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
```

por está:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

---

También cambió el retorno de la conexión:

```
return con;
```

por está:

```
return this.con;
```

---

Igual cambio la conexión con el Driver:

```
con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/centro_int?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull", "root", "1234");
```

Por está:

```
con=(com.mysql.jdbc.Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(db, "root", "1234");
```

---

Espero haya estado claro y sea de ayuda la respuesta.